# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'gcd' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('float64'), dtype('float64')) -> dtype('float64')

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, math

I am trying to find the gcd to obtain the desired array length. so array_length = sub_array_length * number_sub_arrays.

I am want the gcd between array_length and sub_array_length so I can determine number_sub_arrays.

I am using a Gaussian distribution to give me 100 potential sub_array_lengths where hopefully 1 of them provides me large GCD value.

Here is my code so far (I added the value of lp_fill_size and pdx for clarity):

```py
       self.lp_fill_size = 7958
       self.pdx          = 8.296138303238362e-05

       if self.lp_fill_size != 0:
            dx_sub_arr_size = np.round(np.random.normal(0.01, 0.003, 100) / self.pdx)
            num_sub_arr_gcd = np.gcd(dx_sub_arr_size, self.lp_fill_size)
```

The error I get is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_exp_nmr.py", line 157, in <module>
    main()
  File "process_exp_nmr.py", line 127, in main
    dataFormatter.evaluateData()
  File "/workspaces/NMars/NMars/DataStructures/MLFormatter/ExpMLFormatter.py", line 27, in evaluateData
    self._evaluateProton()
  File "/workspaces/NMars/NMars/DataStructures/MLFormatter/ExpMLFormatter.py", line 58, in _evaluateProton
    num_sub_arr_gcd = np.gcd(dx_sub_arr_size, self.lp_fill_size)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'gcd' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('float64'), dtype('float64')) -> dtype('float64')
```

Previous similar stackoverflow questions suggest match the data types. I have tried changing the types of both arguments to np.float64, lists, and integers. I keep getting the same error. I was originally using numpy 1.17 and updated to bumpy 1.19.1 (with conda) and am still getting the same error.

I do not know what else to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both arguments to `np.gcd` have to be integers, not just floats like `12.0`.  `np.round` doesn't make an integer.  You need to `int(...)` or integer divide, `//`.

Comment: yeah you were right. I was casting everything to a float64 but when I cast to int it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the python code that got it to work:

```py
import numpy as np

lp_fill_size = 7958
pdx          = 8.296138303238362e-05

if lp_fill_size != 0:
    dx_sub_arr_size = np.round(np.random.normal(0.01, 0.003, 100) / pdx)
    num_sub_arr_gcd = np.gcd(dx_sub_arr_size.astype(np.int32), lp_fill_size)
```

It worked with casting to np.int32 and with a regular python int.